# Excel vba: Combine workbooks with same names

Tags: excel, vba

I use this code to merge more workbooks to one file. The problem that I discovered is that I have several worksheets with the same name and the code will stop. Any idea how can I fix this problem? For example, if I have 2 worksheets with the name "Sheet123" the program will stop.

```
 Sub mergeFiles()
'Merges all files in a folder to a main file.

 'Define variables:
  Dim numberOfFilesChosen, i As Integer
  Dim tempFileDialog As FileDialog
  Dim mainWorkbook, sourceWorkbook As Workbook
  Dim tempWorkSheet As Worksheet

  Set mainWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook
  Set tempFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

  'Allow the user to select multiple workbooks
   tempFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = True

   numberOfFilesChosen = tempFileDialog.Show

   'Loop through all selected workbooks
   For i = 1 To tempFileDialog.SelectedItems.Count

    'Open each workbook
    Workbooks.Open tempFileDialog.SelectedItems(i), Local:=True

    Set sourceWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook

    'Copy each worksheet to the end of the main workbook
    For Each tempWorkSheet In sourceWorkbook.Worksheets
        tempWorkSheet.Copy After:=mainWorkbook.Sheets(mainWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
    Next tempWorkSheet

    'Close the source workbook
    sourceWorkbook.Close
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What does *"code will stop"* mean? Is there an error message? If so which and in which line?

Comment: One way is to create a control sheet and each time you loop a sheet to record it s name there.

Comment: Please note that your variable declarations are wrong: If you declare `Dim mainWorkbook, sourceWorkbook As Workbook` only `sourceWorkbook` is of type `Workbook` but `mainWorkbook` is of type `Variant`. You need to specify a type for **every** variable in VBA: `Dim mainWorkbook As Workbook, sourceWorkbook As Workbook`. Same for your other declarations.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Run-time error 1004. Method "Open" of object "Workbooks" failed.

Comment: @VasilescuCatalin  So your actual problem is having work**BOOKS** with the same name and not work**SHEETS**? Can you confirm this and [edit] your question to be clear about that?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ yes. I did

Comment: @VasilescuCatalin  But the error *"Method "Open" of object "Workbooks" failed"* is not because of duplicate worksheet names. This error occurs because it cannot open the workbook. So you should figure out first why you get this error. Therefore check the value of `tempFileDialog.SelectedItems(i)` and check if that file exists.

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume that you create a control sheet, you can try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Loop_Sheets()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim wsName As String
    Dim wsList As Range, cell As Range
    Dim Excist As Boolean

    'Loop worksheets
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        'Get Sheet name
        wsName = ws.Name

        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Control")
            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

            If LastRow = 1 Then
                .Cells(LastRow + 1, 1).Value = wsName
            Else
                'Set the list with worksheet names
                Set wsList = .Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(LastRow, 1))

                Excist = False

                For Each cell In wsList
                    'Loop through list
                    If wsName = cell Then
                        Excist = True
                        Exit For
                    End If

                Next

                'If sheet appears in the list
                If Excist = True Then
                'Code'
                'If sheet dont appears in the list
                Else
                    .Cells(LastRow + 1, 1).Value = wsName
                    'Code'
                End If
            End If

        End With

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Actually the problem is in " tempWorkSheet.Copy After:=mainWorkbook.Sheets(mainWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)"

Comment: Error: cannot rename a sheet to the name as another sheet